# texture painting not working after doing all the steps

Tags: texture-painting

So when I try to draw using texture painting nothing happens. Yes, I have done the steps meaning I have unwrapped it using smart UV project, and assigned it a base color, but when I draw on it nothing happens, I can use annotate though but nothing else. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: hello, maybe close the Texture or the Texture Mask, if it still not the problem please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: A base color in the shader and a UV map don’t provide anything for the painted colors to be stored in. You need an image texture to paint onto.

Comment: I got it to work. After doing the steps, under the active tool and workspace setting I clicked on the "X" under brushes and somehow that worked.